# Why is my cookie reset when setting another using php setcookie

Tags: php, cookies

I've found that if I set a cookie with no expiration value and then create another cookie, the first cookie seems to be destroyed. Is this because a new session is created or is it because it is another request?

I've resolved my 'problem' by actually setting an expiration time, but I'm just curious to know what is actually happening when the second cookie is being created.

```
setcookie('cookieA', 'stuff', null, '/');

setcookie('cookieB', 'stuff', time() + 1200, '/');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$expire_time has it's own role in function setcookie and if it's less than now the cookie is deleted. There's no way not to set an expiration time or set it to null. It's simply a specification of cookies to achieve an expiration time (http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2965.html).

If you want the cookie to last forever, just set it to enormously huge number
Good Luck. :)

Comment: When is the cookie deleted though? I can navigate around the site and the cookie remains. Obviously if I close the browser it should be deleted because that's ending the session. But what is the second cookie creation causing?

Comment: it remains also after the closing of a browser. There's nothing happening when the second cookie is created. it's simply created independent on the first cookie. cookie is deleted when the expire time has expired. if you want to manually delete the cookie just set the expire time to the past. (for example `setcookie("cookieB","stuff",time()-1, "/");`

Comment: it just seems like the first cookie is getting deleted, or something is happening to it, after i create the second one. the problem disappears when i set an expiration time rather than leaving it null

Comment: YOU CAN'T SET EXPIRE TIME TO NULL... :)